# JsonPath / Java how to apply Data Type conversion in Filtering

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm using JsonPath java library https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

So far, everything works as expected. There is only one issue I'm trying to solve, but I don't see any function the library provides to support the case.

Technically, I have a Json response data like below

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "start_time": "2021-01-26T11:36:10-0800",
            "insights": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "account_id": "104448579711490",
                        "campaign_id": "6230174444738",
                        "adset_id": "6230236298338",
                        "date_start": "2021-01-12",
                        "date_stop": "2021-02-10",
                        "impressions": "81619",
                        "spend": "33.54"
                    }
                ],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "MAZDZD",
                        "after": "MAZDZD"
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": "6230236298338"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you observe, the value under `impressions` is STRING type, not INTEGER or LONG type. Thus, the current JsonPath setting I'm using in order to pick up the data isn't working as expected

```
$.data[?(@.insights && @.insights.data && @.insights.data[0].impressions > 0)]
```

However, it works well on some Jsonpath testing sites like https://jsonpath.com/

I'm looking for a function that can help to let JsonPath can understand the condition in the filtering and automatically convert the value under `impressions` to INTEGER or LONG. Maybe it's a bug of the lib, I'm going to look into the code and see if I can improve it or not.

Please let me know if you have any workaround to make the setting above work as expected. Really appreciate your information here.

**UPDATE**
@wp78de suggests a trick that works for the case. Thank you.

```
$.data[?(@.insights && @.insights.data && @.insights.data[0].impressions > '0')]
```

Comment: Providing the comparison value as string seems to do the trick: `$.data[?(@.insights && @.insights.data && @.insights.data[0].impressions > '0')]` using Jayways online here: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ Let me know if this works for you as well.

Comment: WOW, the trick works well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice. Let me write this up as a proper answer.

Comment: Sure. I've added it by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it doesn't make a lot of sense, but providing the comparison value as string does the trick:

```
$.data[?(@.insights && @.insights.data && @.insights.data[0].impressions > '0')]
```

I verified this in coded and tested it with [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com) implementation online.
So, the library converts the value internally to the right type to make the comparison work.